# how to store images on server so that image path with id can be store in a property file as map so that we can get images based on id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, controller

all I am new in java I am working on a spring MVC, hibernate, MySQL base project and

I want to store images in a specified folder/directory on server so that I can manage a property file(file name may be something) in which I can store image path with id as map(key as id and value as image path) in that property file and also I want to take some other information from database table also that might contains other image information like uploaded date and description, etc. so how can I do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. It sounds like you already know what you want to do - store a property file that maps ID to image path. What problems are you facing when implementing what you've described?

Comment: I think that if you have a specific folder (path related) for them in the server then it would be very easy to read them by name, and then the name can be your ID as well.

Comment: @jon Skeet actually I google about how to store images in database and somebody tells me to store images in a folder over server and maintain a file in that file store images path with id so based on id I can fetch images instead of storing the images directly database or storing images path in database table so I think i should use a map in which I can store id(PK for DB table)as key and image path as value so that images can be fetch based on key and information like uploaded data can be fetched from database table with id. is this is the preferred way to store images for the fast response?

Comment: hope you got my point

Comment: This is now a very opinion-based question, which isn't really suitable for SO. That sounds fine to me, so long as your file system is suitably replicated to avoid a single point of failure.

Comment: are you using Spring Data for the database piece of your application?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, I got your problem - "You basically want to do two things, first a property file that contains the image location mapped to a key, second manage information related to an image such as upload time and description", so here how I would do it -

I would not recommend you to maintain a properties file due to the fact that CRUD operations will not be that convenient. Also the data you would like to maintain are not properties, these are real-time / dynamic data where your design should have a very good control. You are already using hibernate and MySQL, so why don't you think of maintaining a table (a hibernate entity) that replaces your properties file and also it would be easy for you to maintain other information like upload time and description. All these can be properties of your entity. Moreover you can define relationships with other entities, if required. Coming to the CRUD operations, awesome APIs of hibernate is in rescue. Think about test-ability as well, your design will be easily testable with this approach.

I am already doing this in one of my company project and it's not so bad design.

Comment: ok @Rajib according to my DB design I stored image path in the table and using that  I just have a performance issue that will take time to fetch the images so how much impact it will do performance-wise?

Comment: @amit, how much data are you handling? How do you know that the performance bottle neck is in MySql? If you have identified the issue in MySql, you could try database optimization techniques, try indexing, see for some more suggestions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083192/database-tables-optimized-for-both-read-and-write